# Shiny Daily Data Refresh

Tags: r, shiny

I am doing web scraping and putting the scraped data in shiny app. Web scraping code and data is outside server (in global env). I will deploy this app in shinyapps.io. I want to refresh the data only once in a day so next time if i open the app in the same day, web scraping should **NOT RUN**. Data should process only once in a day, should run it again only next day. I am using `invalidateLater()`, do you think this approach is correct as refreshing the app opens a new session?

```
server <- function(input, output) {

    app_data <- reactive({
      # invalidate 24 hrs later
      invalidateLater(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)
    
      compute_data()
    })

}
```

Comment: It seems reasonable, but I can see some holes. Namely, if/when the R process is interrupted, the data is lost and you'll re-query. You might consider a more formal caching mechanism, perhaps `cachem`, using an on-disk/in-memory layered cache (see their docs). Or, use the `storr` package if you want caching backends like redis or DBI. That way, when the shiny app restarts, you won't lose your cache.

Comment: Thanks. On shinyapps.io, the application directory is reset after an instance is shut down, and there is currently no storage that persists after an application shuts down. Source : https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/caching.html

Comment: If that's the case, then either you're stuck with in-memory (and its volatility), find a redis or database instance you can use (with `storr`), or perhaps write an S3 backend (if you have S3 storage).